# Orient local axis to match mesh's shape

Tags: transforms

This seems like it should be easy, but I've searched SE and YouTube to no avail so far...

I have a mesh in my scene, representing a vehicle's drive shaft. Here it is, with everything else hidden:

[image]

However, the local axis (shown here) lines up with the scene's global axis, which isn't going to be useful when I try rotating the shaft around its length.

How can I transform the mesh's local axes so that, say, the x axis aligns with the drive shaft's length?

And if that's possible, are there any hints on how to make it *exactly* lined up so the shaft doesn't wobble when rotating? Thanks!

Comment: You can change the transform orientation to local or normal. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't _think_ so. When I select the normal axis, it's identical to the local one. Maybe there's a way to tell the normal axis to snap to a face, or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may add a ***custom transform orientation*** based on your object's current orientation. In your case select the object in *Object Mode*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (or click a **'+'** button in a *Transform Orientations* panel of the *Properties Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>). It'll add a new orientation according to your object's position.
[image]

If you have more complicated object with the normals facing in different directions you may select the face/faces with desired angle/angles in *Edit Mode* and then press the buttons mentioned above. It'll orient the 3d gizmo according to the faces' position.
[image]

The newly added orientations (you may add as many as you like) are available in the *Transform Orientation* tab at the bottom bar of the *3D window*.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Actually, for some reason, just adding a custom transform orientation to the object came close, but wasn't exactly lined up, so the shaft wobbled when rotating. So I went into edit mode and selected a face and created an orientation from that. With the pivot point at the object's median point, rotating around the custom x axis is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a workaround.

1. Select an edge loop perpendicular to the required axis. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click
   Duplicate the vertices. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
   Separate them (by selection). <kbd>P</kbd> > By Selection
   [image]
2. Enter edit mode of the newly created object. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
   Select all vertices. <kbd>A</kbd>
   Make a face. <kbd>F</kbd>
   [image]
3. In object mode, add a helper object (e.g. a cube). <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Cube*
4. Enable **Snap during Transform**.
   Set the *Snap Element* to **Face**.
   Activate the last to buttons.
   [image]
5. Snap the helper object (cube) to the face by moving it over. <kbd>G</kbd>
   You probably have to hide all other objects.
    [image]
6. Disable **Snap during Transform**.
   Delete the helper object (cube).<kbd>X</kbd>
   Reset the helper object's location. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This helper object now holds the new orientation.
   [image]
7. Select the original object. <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the helper object and join them. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
   Delete the vertices of the helper object.
   [image]

Comment: Wish I could upvote this 10 times. I've been searching for this for a very long time.

Comment: This will alter the local axis permanently, which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!