# how should i align the axis to the propeller center in this model.so that i can rotate it in animation

Tags: animation

[image]

Hello guys,so i want to create a axis which is alligned to the propellor surface.i want to later animate the propellor

Comment: possible duplicate of recent https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-change-the-axis-of-rotation-of-an-object (and probably many other similar)

Answer (score 1):

You can parent your object to an 'empty' object.

1. Add an empty object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Empty (choose another display type if necessary)
2. Parent your object to the empty (first select the object, then the empty and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Now the Rotation properties of your object can be animated in the empty referential. In my example, just animate the "Z" component and that's it.

Comment: Hi,i am not sure where i am going wrong here,perhaps someone can correct me.i am attaching file link here.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=11sUb9iGLNY7-5p4bacM7Yh-fULalVpS3

Comment: Your propeller is not oriented along any of the three axis in its local coordinate system. You should reposition it edit mode. Start in object mode, Alt+G Alt+R Alt+S for clearing all transformations. Then enter edit mode, and you will see that the object is in a strange position. Align it to an axis, and repeat the process. 
Another solution would be to parent your object to an armature's bone, and to let the bone rotate in pose mode.