# How to make mesh axis in local mode like in custom mode?

Tags: transform-orientation

I have this in local mode

[image]

I created face orientation axes
Now I have this in custom(face) mode
I need this in local mode
[image]

I found the answer 
It consists of 7 steps
[Orient local axis to match mesh's shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69298/orient-local-axis-to-match-meshs-shape)
How can I do it faster?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

How have you rotated the cube?

Local transform orientations do follow the object's transforms.

But If you've rotated the cube in edit mode instead of object mode, then you have rotated only the mesh inside the object. Not the object itself, which rotations haven't changed.

Comment: Yeah I know that it happens when you rotate in edit mode, but i've already done it.
I've rotated it in edit mode and now I need axis like on second image.
Cube is just for instance. I have more complicated objects and I need to make their axis for animation

Comment: Well, there aren't faster ways than the one you already found I'm afraid. Except avoiding this situation from the beginning, or correcting the object's orientation.