# Rotating in blender, Plane's Propeller

Tags: animation

I've been thinking or searching for solution about this, I've been trying to make the propeller spin but for some reason

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcD4-3UVCSI

Comment: Someone else has had this problem just t'other day!  See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137781/how-to-animate-a-prsopeller-on-the-axis-of-rotation

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Thanks for the info, im new here so im kind of not use to it hehehehe.