# How to get more speed for the blade

Tags: animation

Im creating Table Fan. For the blade the rotation looks slow. I added Motion blur yet to it looks slow. Any suggestion how to increase the speed to look more realistic.

[image]

With the reference of the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137781/how-to-animate-a-propeller-on-the-axis-of-rotation) **Edgel3D**

Whats missing im not getting the same effect in the answer shown. I tried all the setting in the answer. Any suggestion what im missing. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note - this Blend file was from Version 2.77a.   The same principle applies for later versions.

[image]

Once the rotation is set up, it often looks more convincing to fade in a semmi-transparent disc whilst also fading out the propeller to semmi- transparency, reversing the procedure as it slows down.

In this example the Material slot's 'Alpha' slider was keyframed for both the prop & disc.

Layer 2 is a turbine propeller whereas Layer 7 is a piston engine with compression.  The compression kick-back is done in the graph editor.
(see the green 'Y rotation' f-curve where the prop stops)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will find things appear to move slower at higher frame rates.  This is because your eye has more information to work with.  Adding motion blur will help by filling in space between frames so it doesn't appear to jitter rather than rotate but at higher frame rates, the motion blur trail will be shorter, making the motion seem slower.

Using a lower frame rate with motion blur will make it appear faster.

You could render an image of the rotor with motion blur at a low frame rate and add it as a plane parented to the rotor.  This will give you the long trail you'd expect, even at high frame rates.

raising the rotation speed with motion blur enabled should also do this but I'm assuming you have already tried this.

Comment: I have attach my file. Can u plz show me in the blend file how it works. Thanks

Comment: @Edgel3D blend file plz so that i can go through whats going on. Thanks

Comment: Apologies @Kieran - Dropped my comment to Atek here in error.  Was supposed to go up at the question.