# How to make Propeller Motion blur spin

Tags: animation, shaders, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I'm using a toon shader in blender for my animation project, and i'm trying to get a spinning propeller effect like this, but motion blur just isn't really getting the same effect, its just a blurry for some frames but for the most part it doesn't really look like its spinning really fast,
any ideas on how may i achieve something like this?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like motion blur is really what you are after here. Seems more like stylized interpretation of it. So that's probably what you should be looking for - how to draw a stylized spinning propeller, not motion blur.

Comment: This might help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178537/how-to-get-more-speed-for-the-blade/179223#179223

Answer (score 3):

Motion blur works relative to the frames you got. The issue with high speed motions like rotations and shakes, is that you just don't have enough frames to describe the motion to begin with.

A good example of that issue is in 2021's Dune: https://youtu.be/OHPkdMGI6D4?t=799

> We're talking such a high frequency of motion that, [within a single frame], not only does [the wing] go down, it goes back up, and back down, and back up again.

One way to fix that issue is to use substeps (Eevee only), or render even more frames per second:

[image: steps]

But you can only go so far before it costs you significantly more render time for diminishing returns.

The other, simpler way, is just to reduce the motion itself. Unless you really want absolute photorealism, you can do most propellers with about five revolutions per second. That's going from 0° to 1800°. Here's how it looks in 24fps with default Eevee motion blur:

[image: propeller 5 rps]

[image]